# I want to edit gridview after it is filtered by cascade dropdowns

Tags: asp.net, gridview, edit, cascade

Of the 2 cascading dropdowns, second one is to select distinct **book_author** from Products where **cat_id**(category- which is not primary key) is matching the one selected in the first dropdown. Table product has primary key book_id, cat_id,**book_author**.. the 2 dropdowns are ddlcat and ddlauthor

I would appreciate complete code as an answer

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlcat" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" BackColor="White" ForeColor="Black" Height="30px" Width="100px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlcat_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem Text = "--Select Category--" Value = ""></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlauthor"  AutoPostBack="True" runat="server" Height="30px" Width="200px"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlauthor_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:listitem value="" text="--Select Author--" ></asp:listitem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        ddlcat.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
        String strConnString = ConfigurationManager
            .ConnectionStrings["abcd2"].ConnectionString;
        String strQuery = "select cat_id, cat_name from Category";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = strQuery;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            ddlcat.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            ddlcat.DataTextField = "cat_name";
            ddlcat.DataValueField = "cat_id";
            ddlcat.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
protected void ddlcat_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ddlauthor.Items.Clear();
    ddlauthor.Items.Add(new ListItem("--Select Author--", ""));


    ddlauthor.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
    String strConnString = ConfigurationManager
        .ConnectionStrings["abcd2"].ConnectionString;
    String strQuery = "select DISTINCT book_author FROM Products " +
                       "WHERE cat_id=@cat_id";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cat_id",
        ddlcat.SelectedItem.Value);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = strQuery;
    cmd.Connection = con;

    try
    {
        con.Open();
        ddlauthor.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        ddlauthor.DataTextField = "book_author";
        ddlauthor.DataValueField = "book_author";

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
        con.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is that the second drop down shows "select" and on clicking the dropdown shows another "select" but not the distinct book_author

Comment: "I would appreciate complete code as an answer" Wow, StackOverflow is question - answer site : is that a question ?

Comment: @dkg Actually its my first time in stackoverflow and I was in a bit of a hurry :)

Comment: Also the question is about cascade only not gridview, sorry guys .Ill have to post new question again